# Is *ngFor stable for lists in Nativescript Angular?

Tags: angular, nativescript

**Edit:** I have asked a related question about what the current state of RadList View is (does it exist anymore?) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712148/does-radlistview-still-exist-nativescript-pro-ui).

**Original question:**
Is *ngFor ok to use for lists in Nativescript?

Normally, I find people recommending RadListView, but for ease of use and being able to customize the list, I strongly prefer *ngFor. However, I recently had a few glitches using *ngFor, so I want to be sure it is stable in the most recent Nativescript.

Details:

In my iOS app, built with Nativescript, I have a few two level lists--lists with categories and then items in each category--like:

```
-People
---Joe
---Suzy

-Animals
---Fito
---Spot

-Places
---Park
---Town
```

I originally tried to build this type of with RadListView from the Pro UI, but I found building a two level list overly cumbersome. I need to be able to load and then manipulate the data in various ways, and it seemed like RadListView was made for limited customizing.

This [discussion](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-two-level-list/5283/4) mentions the "grouping function" as the way to do it with RadListView, but that was an inflexible approach for the type of data I have. Using basic ListView was even worse in terms of inflexibility and customizability.

So I have been using basic *ngFor, like:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of things">
        <Label text="{{item.type}}" (tap)="clickToShowEntries()"></Label>
        <StackLayout *ngFor="let entry of item.type" style="margin-left: 80px">
            <Label text="{{entry}}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>   
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Is there a problem using *ngFor instead of RadListView? After updating to the most recent Nativescript and CLI, the list on my app didn't seem as stable--a few times in testing some of the categories overlapped with each other randomly and the screen was glitchy. I have not reproduced that error, but it made me wonder whether there is a problem using *ngFor.

Comment: you can customize listviews, so i dont see your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView and RadListView are components that are using the native approaches for handling lists. Both are using recycling and virtualization (check [this blog post](https://medium.com/@alexander.vakrilov/faster-nativescript-listview-with-multiple-item-templates-8f903a32e48f) for details) which are greatly improving performance. Both ListView and RadListView are supporting multiple templates and customization and even more - they are aligned with the mobile APIs as behind the scenes there are native elements that are creating these components.

The Angular's `ngFor` is a structural directive that is not optimized for large lists that will be loaded on a mobile device.

So the short answer is to use `ngFor` only for short lists and `ListView` / `RadListView` for anything that you might consider heavy.

Comment: Great description. Thank you. Do you have a recommendation for how to do a two (or even three) level RadListView? I have to load data from a few sources, put them together in the category structure I mentioned above, and then allow the user to hide and show categories. Easy to do with *ngFor, but it seems cumbersome with RadListView--as mentioned, I had previously looked at the "grouping function" but it seemed too limiting.  The easiest would be if you could have a RadListView within another RadListView. But I have not been able to get this to work.

Comment: Nesting of the listview. radlistviews or scroll views (any component that has a scroller) is not supported. Still, I would approach the problem by using the ordering, sorting and grouping data operations along with the appropriate UI. http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/data-operations

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will re-look at the grouping function. I think last time the issue was that my page will have to load before all the data comes in, and that created issues. For example, bc of pulling data from different spots and then parsing it, I may not know all the categories right away, and that seemed problematic for grouping function. What about just having an *ngFor within a RadListView? Like RadListView category...*ngFor (item of category)...  Maybe not optimal, but if the *ngFor portion is not too heavy maybe that can work.

Comment: If you're using `ngFor` to still manage the state of a large list you'll likely run into the same performance problems you would have ran into had you just used only `ngFor`. From what I've heard about NativeScript and general native app development in general, sometimes you have to rethink how you will layout information for the end user compared to a website.

Comment: Thanks. This is all helpful--and helps explain why I randomly saw a glitch when using *ngFor for a list (bc the native view struggles a little with a larger list if using *ngFor). I'll see what I can do with RadListView.

Comment: I see in the discussion I linked to in my original question the issue--the grouping function in RadListView limits how you can style the data, and its not clear how to use it for a complex array. So it works for: stuff=[{category: 'person', name: 'jim'}, {category: 'animal', name: lion...}], but not clear how to get it to work for an array like: stuff=[{category: 'person', people: [{name: 'jim', age: '25'}, {name: 'Jill', age: '28'}] }, {category: 'animal', animals: [{name: 'lion', age: 10}, etc...  I will see what I can make work but I think this was the kind of problem I found before.

Comment: @NickIliev please see question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885975/how-to-catch-click-on-category-header-with-radlistview-grouping-function-nativ. Is there a way to catch the click on the category headers with RadListView? seems like you need grouping function, but grouping function hides the category header. So it seems you cannot catch a click event on the category header--which is a very significant limitation of RadListView.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave @Nick Lliev's answer as the accepted answer, but I wanted to note: I have discovered why *ngFor appeared "buggy" for iOS after upgrading to Nativescript 5.0+. In Nativescript 5.0+, it looks like the team made some changes to make Nativescript work better for iOS's safe area. This affected the style/formatting of items like *ngFor.

In my case, after the ugprade, *ngFor lists that used to work perfectly started doing buggy things like having random large white space on the screen, and entries overlapping.

I was able to correct this by adding `iosOverflowSafeArea="false"` as a header in my html (like `<StackLayout iosOverflowSafeArea="false"`...). With this change, my *ngFor lists seem to be back to normal.

In fact, in testing on my device, my *ngFor list work better than my RadListView lists with grouping function. The *ngFor lists are perfectly smooth, while the RadListView lists are a little jerky in the scrolling. Both lists have same amount of data--around 40 entries. Anyone know why *ngFor might actually scroll more smoothly than RadListView?