# Does RadListView still exist (Nativescript pro-ui)

Tags: nativescript

**Edit:** I have posted the higher level version of getting RadListView to work with the grouping function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731449/how-to-1-isolate-click-on-category-and-2-show-hide-data-with-radlistview-gro). The question here addresses just getting RadListView to work in its basic form.

---

I have been away from Nativescript pro ui for a few months, and now am trying to put together a multilevel list (with categories, items in each category; and user able to hide and show categories with tap). From the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707816/is-ngfor-stable-for-lists-in-nativescript-angular) I see that *ngFor is not the stable way to do a multilevel list (though it is the easiest!)

So now I am trying to use the pro ui listview, but the documentation is a few months old and uses the term "RadListView".

Does RadListView still exist? And what is the best documentation for doing a two or three level list in Nativescript Angular?

**Details in case helpful:**

So I am now trying to use RadListView to do this, but it is not clear to me that RadListView exists at all anymore. The market place listing for Nativescript pro-ui says the old pro-ui has been deprecated, and each item of the pro ui now must be downloaded individually ([link](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-pro-ui)).

It lists an [npm listing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ui-listview) for the pro ui "ListView", that uses the term "ListView". But, when you click on any of the documentation / sample code links in that npm listing, they all use the term "RadListView" (the old formulation).

I am not able to get RadListView to work. Even for the most simple example (which worked a few months ago), if I use RadListView in my component html, the screen is blank.

For example, I am trying to do a multilevel list. Looks like the "grouping" function in RadListView is the (only?) way to do this. I have cut and pasted in the code from [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/data-operations), but it does not work--blank screen with "RadListView" and no data with just "ListView".

example:

ts:

```
import { ListViewEventData, LoadOnDemandListViewEventData } from "nativescript-ui-listview";
import { RadListViewComponent } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
  public arrayItems = [
                      {category:'person', name: 'jim', description: 'a very 
                       nice person'}, 
                      {category:'jungle animal', name: 'lion', description: 
                       'king of the jungle'}
                     ]

  private _myGroupingFunc: (item: any) => any;

   constructor (){
       this.myGroupingFunc = (item: arrayItems) => {
            return item.category;
        };
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
   }

   get myGroupingFunc(): (item: any) => any {
        return this._myGroupingFunc;
    }

    set myGroupingFunc(value: (item: any) => any) {
        this._myGroupingFunc = value;
    }
}...
```

html:

```
<StackLayout>
   <ListView [items]="arrayItems" enableCollapsibleGroups="true" [groupingFunction]="myGroupingFunc" >
     <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-arrayItem="item" >
      <StackLayout>
        <Label [text]="arrayItem.name"></Label>
        <Label [text]="arrayItem.description"></Label>    
      </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

With this code, copied from [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/data-operations), there are not entries that appear (just the lines of a ListView with nothing inside). If I say "RadListView" instead of "ListView", the screen is entirely blank. I would definitely appreciate if someone has updated code for this action.

Comment: You have some errors in your source, so I'm guessing you retyped it instead of copy-paste. Specifically, this does not have a `@Component` decorator, and you have attempted to use `arrayItems` as a type instead of `any`.

Comment: My actual source has a lot more (including @component)--it was edited for brevity. In the meantime, does RadListView still exist?

Comment: Here is an example of a working playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mUqD4Y

Comment: I am not able to get it to work quite yet--but I am getting closer. However, I do get a warning saying "Collapsible Group" is not supported on iOS. I need to have this list work like an accordion: load the page, and only the categories show. Click on a category, and show the entries of that category. Click that cat again, and hide the entries. AND I will have to know which category has been clicked. This is easy with *ngFor.  Will this be possible with grouped RadListView?

Comment: I am not able to get the playground to work. Is it updated for NS 5.0+ and the newest pro-ui plugin? I just get [object object] on the page.

Comment: When you say that you're not able to get the playground to work, are you doing something other than using the QR code in the Playground app?

Comment: I have tried both: 1) running the playground app on my phone (not working--though that could be bc of app on my phone), and 2) copying and pasting the ts and html files directly. If that code is correct for NS 5.0+ and updated pro ui, then the error must be about how I have downloaded the plugin / list it on my app. I did '$ tns plugin add nativescript-ui-listview'. Are there specific imports I need in app.module.ts or in the component ts file? I do not find guidance on that.

Comment: 1) Maybe your app needs an update. It is very unusual that the playground produces something different on two devices. 2) Use the "Download" button; don't copy-paste.

Comment: That code downloads a lot of the pro-ui components, so its tough to tell what is essential. My main question is what  I need to import in app.module.ts and my component ts to get it to work in my NS 5.0 app.

Comment: Well, there's `NativeScriptUIListViewModule` as described [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/getting-started#adding-a-radlistview-to-your-template).

Comment: Edit: I ran a few things, like "TNS update". Basics seem to be working now.  The syntax seems to be "import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";". Before running $tns update, I got this error:  "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Metadata for "TNSListView.TKListViewHeaderCell" found but symbol not available at runtime."

Comment: Last question for today: Is there a way to isolate a click on the category itself when using the grouping function? In the playground you linked to, there is a (itemTap) event in the RadListView. But that seems to go off if anywhere in the displayed array is shown. Is there a way to know if just the category header (supplied by the grouping function) has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ian MacDonald for his help. RadListView does remain the Nativescript pro-ui version of list view. It works for me like this:

```
$ tns plugin add nativescript-ui-listview

$ npm i

$ tns update //don't know why/what was out of date, but features like the grouping function did not work for me until I ran this.
```

coolComponent.module.ts:  (if using lazy loading, I was only able to get RadListView to work by importing the module directly into the component module)

```
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";
...
@ngModule({
   imports: [
    ...
   NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
  ]
...
```

coolComponent.html:

```
<GridLayout>
    <RadListView [items]="cats" >
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-cat="item">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label [text]="cat"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

coolComponent.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ListViewEventData, RadListView } from "nativescript-ui-listview";
...

export class CoolComponent {
    public cats = ['tiger', 'lion', 'puma']

    constructor(){
   }
}
```