# How to catch click on category header with RadListView grouping function? (Nativescript)

Tags: nativescript

I had previously asked about a few items re: RadListView's grouping function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731449/how-to-make-an-accordion-list-with-radlistview-nativescript). I didn't get an answer, so wanted to try to focus on hopefully the simplest part: how do I catch the click event on a category header?

Normally, this would be pretty easy, like `<Label text="group.category" (tap)="youClickedTheCategory()"></Label>`.

But using the grouping function with RadListView, the category does not have an html entry, so how do I know if the user clicks on the category header instead of somewhere else in the group?

If example code is helpful:

html:

```
<GridLayout>
    <RadListView [items]="places" [groupingFunction]="myGroupingFunc">
        <ng-template let-place="item" >
            <StackLayout>
                <Label [text]="place.city"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

ts:

```
   public places = [
        {country: 'US', city: 'New York'}, 
        {country: 'US', city: 'Los Angeles'},     
        {country: 'Canada', city: 'Toronto'},
        {country: 'England', city: 'London'}
        ]

    constructor() {
    }

    myGroupingFunc(value) {
      return value.country;
    }
```

Result would be:

```
Canada
--Toronto

England
--London

US
--New York
--Los Angeles
```

Goal: know if the user clicks on the country category header (here, Canada , England, or US)--instead of the user clicking on the whole group.

Using Nativescript Angular (for iOS).

Comment: RadListView doesn't support sections that's a iOS specific feature. But what you could do is to use different templates, one for header and another for items. By the binding context passed in to itemTap event, you have to distinguish between header & item in it.

Comment: That's surprising that this basic idea (catch when a user clicks on something on the page) does not exist. I would need each entry to show up under its category header. If there was one template for header and a separate for entries, wouldn't they show up separately on the page?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean you have to catch events separately. You can still use itemTap even on ListView and filter if it's a header template.

Comment: What I meant: Won't the header template and item template show up separate on the page? So would show up as England, Canada, US, and then below all of them Toronto, London, New York, Los Angeles?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant by using different templates for header and item but still managing your data by injecting group elements in the right position may be difficult but possible. I personally prefer to use `nativescript-accordion` which works great for grouping elements, expand particular section on tap etc.,

Comment: The accordion plugin is cool, but what if I don't want the show/hide functionality? I just want to show the category headers and the entries below at the same time for all groups. I don't see an ability on the accordion plugin to turn off the show/hide activity (it always seems to start with the entries hidden, and you need to click the header to show them. I want the entries shown on page load)

Comment: You may use the `selectedIndexes` array to pre-expand all the groups. You may write a simple override to avoid collapse / expand upon tapping header.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. Is the plugin production ready?

Comment: What kind of override do you have in mind? I don't see that in the docs.

Comment: Per conversation on slack, accordion plugin is having some trouble on ios with selectedIndexes header. I don't think a plugin should be necessary for this simple task: have a list with category headers and entries. and know when the user clicks on the category header.

Comment: Is there another way of having a list with category headers and entries below OTHER than RadListView grouping function? If so, that might be what I need. Grouping function seems to limited bc it hides the category header from programmatic action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer, based on this github discussion [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/973). The key is the tkGroupTemplate in RadListView.  For NativeScript (and iOS--probably works for Android too), if you want to have a list that has category headers and entries below, and you want to be able to click on the category headers, the present method is to use tkGroupTemplate.

Here is an example:

```
$ tns plugin add nativescript-ui-listview
```

component html:

```
<GridLayout>
    <RadListView [items]="places" [groupingFunction]="myGroupingFunc">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-place="item">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label [text]="place.city" (tap)="listEntryTap(place.city)"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template tkGroupTemplate let-country="category">
            <StackLayout ios:height="25">
                <Label [text]="country" (tap)="headerTap(country)"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

ts: (component ts file)

```
public places = [
         {country: 'US', city: 'New York'}, 
         {country: 'US', city: 'Los Angeles' },     
         {country: 'Canada', city: 'Toronto'},
         {country: 'England', city: 'London'},
         {country: 'US', city: 'Chicago'},
         {country: 'Canada', city: 'Calgary'}      
]
...
constructor(){}
...
myGroupingFunc(value) {
   return value.country;
}

headerTap(country){
    console.log('you tapped this country header: ' + country)
}

listEntryTap(city){
    console.log('you tapped this city entry: ' + city)
}
```

module.ts: (module for the component--if using lazy loading of components. If not using lazy loading, this probably would go in the main app.module.ts file)

```
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ...
   NativeScriptUIListViewModule 
  ]
...
```

And that should produce the following, with headers (countries) and entries (cities) separately clickable:

```
Canada
Toronto
Calgary

England
London

US
New York
Los Angeles
Chicago
```

It looks like this comes with some default formatting (the headers have a different background color automatically)--but you can override that with your own styles.

Without the `ios:height="25"`(or whatever height) some of the category headers go over the entries.

Otherwise, though, this seems to work for iOS and NativeScript 5.0+ (and, I assume, earlier versions too).